# Swift async await on Promise func that use SwiftyBluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm using `SwiftyBluetooth` in an iOS App, a closure wrapper to `CoreBluetooth`. I've created a Bluetooth singleton wrapper where I have useful method that are chainable with `PromiseKit`.

I'm trying to write a method that founds the nearest peripheral (based on RSSI) and to make it more robust, I would like to 'find the same peripheral as the nearest for x times in a row' (with x a parameter).

This is the two method I've written.

The first one simply search the nearest peripheral and works great.

```
func searchNearest(withService service: BluetoothService = .configuration,
                   timeout: TimeInterval = 5) -> Promise<(Peripheral,[String : Any])
{
    return Promise { seal in
        var nearestPeripheral: Peripheral? = nil
        var advData: [String : Any] = [:]
        var maxRSSI = -1000
        
        SwiftyBluetooth.scanForPeripherals(withServiceUUIDs: [service.rawValue],
                                           timeoutAfter: timeout)
        { scanResult in
            switch scanResult {
            case .scanStarted:
                break
                
            case .scanResult(let peripheral, let advertisementData, let RSSI):
                
                if let name = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"] as? String,
                   name.count > 5,
                   let rssi = RSSI
                {
                    print("name: \(name) , rssi: \(rssi)")
                    if rssi > maxRSSI {
                        maxRSSI = rssi
                        nearestPeripheral = peripheral
                        advData = advertisementData
                        print("name: \(name)")
                    }
                }
                break
                
            case .scanStopped(let peripherals, let error):
                print("stopped")
                if let nearest = nearestPeripheral {
                    print("fulfill")
                    seal.fulfill((nearest,advData))
                } else {
                    print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    seal.reject(NSError.init(domain: "", code: 0))
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second one has a while loop and call with await asyn the first method:

```
func searchNearest(inARow: Int,
                   withService service: BluetoothService = .configuration,
                   timeout: TimeInterval = 3) -> Promise<(Peripheral,[String : Any])>
{
    return Promise { seal in
        Task {
            let max = 100
            var i = 0
            var found = 0
            var name: String = ""
            
            while found < inARow && i < max {
                print("max: \(max), i: \(i), name: \(name)")
                
                let nearest = try await searchNearest(withService: service, timeout: timeout).async()
                print("nearest \(nearest.0.name)")
                if nearest.0.name == name {
                    found += 1
                } else {
                    name = nearest.0.name ?? ""
                    found = 1
                }
                
                if found == inARow {
                    seal.fulfill(nearest)
                }
                
                i += 1
            }
            
            seal.reject(NSError.init(domain: "", code: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first time that this line is executed all works fine

```
let nearest = try await searchNearest(withService: service, timeout: timeout).async()
```

but at the second turn, they never returns.
The scan bluetooth never terminate, but for sure I'm passing a really short timeout (3 seconds).

Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks.